# Oracle Apex Form fields showing pre populated values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a form with report in oracle apex 5.1 based on an existing table. The problem is when I run the form page to add an entry some Number Fields shows pre populated values. I have no idea why this is happening. I want all my form fields to be blank. My form template is "Blank with attribute".

Could anyone help solve this problem???

Comment: Your form template is unrelated to the form fields being pre-populated, btw.  Check the specific fields if they have a default value being set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like one of two things are happening here:

1.) your form is retaining the previous value. If this is the case, ensure that when branching to the form that you are clearing the cache of the page.

2.) you have a process, likely an ARF (Automatic Row Fetch). If so, the ARF is grabbing data from your table and assigning it to each item that has a source of DB column. You may want to review the process to ensure that you're using a unique key to fetch records.

Comment: Yes. The 1st event was happening here. I did not clear the cache of the page.